# Get the displayed fields of a MS Project file

Tags: c#, ms-office, office-interop, ms-project

I need to get the field used in a MS project file by C#.
My program need to provide users to choose one or many of them and I don't want to provide **ALL** the fileds (text1, text2, number1, ...) but the field that are displayed in the project file as "Start date", "End Date" and custom fields created by the users for the project file.

Does anyone have an idea?

I use COM object.

Answer (score 1):

I found my solution.

I can access to the fields of a task by its name with:

```
task.GetField(msProject.Application.FieldNameToFieldConstant(fieldName,PjFieldType.pjTask))
```

Comment: This throws an error if the field name doesn't exist. Do you know of a method for checking if the field name exists?